# Django celery unregistered task | relative imports

Tags: python, django, celery, python-import, periodic-task

I'm trying implement periodic tasks in django app by using celery (v 4.3.0). My `tasks.py` looks like below:

```
# forepy is the simple package created by me
from forepy import Instrument
from forepy import oanda_api
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def sum_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Problem is that celery worker returns error `Received unregistered task of type 'fxsignal.tasks.sum_number'`. I think that cause of problem is two import statements at the top of `tasks.py` (forepy imports). When I comment out those two lines my periodic task `sum_numbers` works correctly. For your reference, structure of `forepy` package is as below:

```
forepy\
    downloaders\
        __init.py__
        oanda_api.py
    __init__.py
    instruments.py
    utils.py
```

And `forepy`'s **init**.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Top-level package for forepy."""

__author__ = """Elgin Jahangirov"""
__email__ = 'cahangirove@gmail.com'
__version__ = '0.2.0'


from forepy.instrument import Instrument
from forepy.downloaders import oanda_api

__all__ = ['Instrument', 'oanda_api']
```

I've read [this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports) part of celery documentation and get rid of all `.` imports in my `forepy` package, but still problem exists. What can I do further to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Celery failed silently in this case, although one of dependency of another package (which is dependency of `forepy`) is not installed in current environment. I can only detect that after adding below configuration in django project's `settings.py` (thanks to [@cagrias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4665915/cagrias)):

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'your_app.tasks',
    'forepy.instrument',
    'forepy.downloaders',
)
```

By adding above configuration to django settings, terminal reported import error, which was actual cause of not registering task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your imports such that:

```py
from forepy import instruments
from forepy.downloaders import oanda_api
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def sum_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b
```

You also need to inform celery about your other django app modules (forepy module in your case) in your `settings.py` file such that:

```py
CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'your_app.tasks',
    'forepy.instruments',
    'forepy.downloaders',
)
```

Comment: I've updated `forepy.__init__.py` as you said, but it still says unregistered task.

Comment: You need to update your ```tasks.py``` not your ```__init__.py```.

Comment: Ok. But how should I structure `forepy.__init__.py` then? Please take a look at current structure that I included in my question. Currently I can't `from forepy import instruments` since, `instruments` is not exported in `__init__.py`?

Comment: Where is your ```tasks.py```? You shouldn't need to edit any ```__init__.py```s. What error do you get when you edit your ```tasks.py``` as in my answer?

Comment: `tasks.py` is inside djangoo app. `__init__.py` is in the forepy package, which is installed in virtual environment. Ok, with your modifications, it does throw any error, but `sum_numbers` task is still unregistered.

Comment: You need to register your task following this guideline: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html Just make sure you've created ```celery.py``` and add your celery.app in ```__init__.py``` under your django project (the directory where ```settings.py``` exits)

Comment: Problem is not related to celery configuration. As I said, when I comment out `forepy` imports `sum_numbers` task becomes registered and works as expected.

Comment: I solved it! Problem was that `requests` module was one of the dependencies and not installed in venv. After installing that, it now works correctly. It is surprising that why celery was failing silently. Anyway thank you for your support and help!

Comment: You can run celery with loglevel=INFO parameter as ```celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info``` to get detailed logs. I hope that helps for your future development.

Comment: I was running with loglevel `debug`, but it was not printing out any import error.